# "No Bootable Device" even after several installations

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, system-installation

I have purchased a new acer aspire E 15, E5-573 laptop and myself trying to install ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit) OS. I have tried installing more than 8 times and installation successfully completed each time. But finally when I restarting the system, the installed os cannot be booted and "No Booting Device" message is coming.

Myself tried both USB as well as DVD installations but every time result is same. I also checked BIOS using F2 key and set the Boot from HDD Device. But of no use. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Do you install with UEFI or with Legacy? And how is the BIOS set up, UEFI or Legacy (sometimes called CMS)?

Comment: Previously, I installed with UEFI. Now again trying with Legacy mode :(

Comment: Have you disabled secure boot in BIOS and switched off Windows Hibernation feature?

Comment: yes...  myself configured that too @Ashu

Comment: Finally, it was solved by using Legacy BIOS mode. When using legacy mode, first installation gives gurb error and when once again installed, it was successful at second time.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Fast Startup. Windows 8.1 and presumably future versions have a feature called Fast Startup. When it is enabled -- and it is enabled by default -- Windows shuts down in a hybrid state, somewhere between a full shutdown and a "sleep" state. The dual boot manager which Ubuntu will install (called grub) does not presently (March 2015) know how to start Windows from this hybrid state. You must therefore disable Fast Startup if you ever want to use Windows again after installing Ubuntu. Just how to do that is best left to the documentation of your particular version of Windows. But do not fail to do it, or you will never boot Windows again.

There also used to be an option to tell GRUB where to install the boot loader. Did you use this option during install? Perhaps you did not tell GRUB to install the bootloader on the correct partition.